# How to stop Security Warnings in Google Chrome for Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I need to bypass/prevent privacy error message of "Your connection is not private" or automatically proceed to  (unsafe) .
I can accept unsafe connection by clicking on advance but, it's not permanent.It will again shows after system restart.
Chrome version is "51.0.2704.63 m"

I have tried various links but still I don't found any fix for this.

I have tried this but not getting setting "Remember decisions to proceed through SSL errors for a specified length of time. "
  : https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/63157-how-can-i-stop-google-chrome-showing-me-a-connection-not-private-message

Adding site as trusted site also not worked for me : http://kb.mcgill.ca/?portalid=2&articleid=1925#tab:homeTab:crumb:8:artId:1925:src:article

Comment: Why not add the certificate to your trust store?

Comment: I have installed certificate into "Trusted root certification authority " but still not working.Message is still showing in chrome.

Comment: What OS are you using: Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Hi, any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 2):

By adding your self signed certificate as trusted root you won't get the warning page anymore but the red lock will remain. You will need to do this for each certificate you want Chrome to trust.

1. View the certificate by clicking the red lock next to the URL and clicking "Certificate"
2. Go to the "Details" tab and "Copy to file..." and run through the wizard
3. Go to chrome://settings/?search=manage+certificates and click "Manage Certificates"
4. Add the certificate you just saved

Note: Chrome uses the Windows certificate store but you can access it as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old and you might have already got answer to the question. However, i would like to provide more insight into removing the security warning from browsers. Basically, any browser confirms below list items before marking a website/url secure:

1. Match the base DNS with that of the certificate CN (Note that the port number doesn't come into picture in this case). For example, if you are accessing https://example.com:8445/something, the certificate CN should be "example.com"
2. The self-signed certificate has to be imported into the respective trust store (Root Certification Authorities) of the system.
3. The certificate must have a SAN (Subject Alternative Name), that matches the DNS. With respect to previous example, the certificate must have at least one SAN equivalent to "example.com". This is a must, and most of the folks miss out on this point, and could not understand why the browser doesn't trust the certificate.

Now, all the above 3 criteria cannot be met unless the certificate is signed by a CA. However, there is an easy way. Go to https://freesslcert.org/ to receive a completely free 1 year certificate with all the above criteria incorporated. Follow the steps mentioned in https://freesslcert.org/trust-freesslcert-in-browser and you are all set.

Comment: A link to a website for getting SSL certificates that has its own certificate expired does not look trustworthy. Use https://letsencrypt.org instead